# find files with similar names and then narrow down further

Tags: shell-script, shell

My media player marks video files as having been watched by creating a new file with the exact same name but with an added ".t" extension (in the same folder). For example, after I've watched "SeinfeldS07E02.mp4" it will produce a file named "SeinfeldS07E02.mp4.t"

I want to have all watched video files automatically moved to another folder, and was thinking that perhaps the best way would be via a shell script that will find the *.t file, and then find the original file from which its name was based, and have THAT file moved to another folder. I already have a very simple script that can find and move the *.t file, but I have no idea how to narrow it down further. Is this even doable?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid surprises from filenames containing spaces or worse it might be worthwhile to run everything directly from `find`:

```
find /PATH/TO/SOURCE -name '*.mp4' \
    -exec sh -c '[ -e "$1.t" ]
                 && mv -- "$1" /PATH/TO/TARGET
                 && rm -- "$1.t"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: @Jim Make sure there is no whitespace character after the `\ ` in the first line (it must be the last character on the line). Or leave the `\ ` away and put the second line at the end of the first.

Comment: This worked fine when I directly entered it into the command line, but when I tried to run it as a shell script, I got the following:  (line break)

: unknown primary or operator  (line break)
/mnt/HDD/1.sh: -exec: not found

Comment: @Jim Please read my comment above, you have a typo in your script.

Comment: Problem solved - I changed the script heading from "#!/bin/sh" to "#!/bin/bash". Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

> for i in $(find /path -type f -name "*.mp4.t") ; do mv $(echo $i | sed
>   "s/.mp4.t/.mp4/") /path/to/otherfolder/ ; done

may be suffisant I guess

simulate it :

```
[root@h2g2w ~]# mkdir {toto,titi}
[root@h2g2w ~]# touch toto/{a,b,a.t,b.t,c}
[root@h2g2w ~]# for i in $(find toto/ -type f -name "*.t") ; do mv $(echo $i | sed "s/\.t//") titi/ ; done
[root@h2g2w ~]# ls -l titi
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0  1 janv. 15:13 a
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0  1 janv. 15:13 b
[root@h2g2w ~]# rm -rf toto titi
[root@h2g2w ~]# #OK only a & b have moved
```

Comment: You should remove the marker file as well,probably

Comment: Several [BashPitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) here (applicable to other Bourne-like shells - not just `bash`)